# how to create my own 'cout' and 'cerr' class

Tags: c++, cout, cin, ostream

How do I create my own class that behaves exactly like: `std::cout` & `std::cerr`.

I am writing a mini operating system and this is a requirement, having these as modules there.

The code will look like:

```
myNewCoutClass myCout; // create cout behavioral class
myNewCerrClass myCerr; // create cerr behavioral class

myCout << someString << endl; // prints the string
myCerr << someString << endl; // prints the string as error
```

Comment: The `new` is not necessary. In fact, your example won't work until you dereference `myCout` and `myCErr`, which are pointers. Avoid the pointers.

Comment: _"failed to find anywhere answers for that, i will appreciate simple answers."_ That smells a bit contradictorily, not? Your question seems way too broad. You may start out with studying the implementation of `std::cin` and `std::cout`.

Comment: what i found was mostly overriding of the "<<" operators in classes i use, which is not useful for me.

Comment: @Tango_Chaser: It may be. We can't say, because we have no idea how you want these classes to work, beyond having an ostream interface

Comment: @Lightness Races: I want the classes to behave as the simplest cout functions possible. to receive a string and pint it to the screen.

Comment: @Tango_Chaser: "Print it to the screen" is exceptionally vague. How is your "screen" implemented? What is it?

Comment: @Lightness Races: the user will be able to see on the screen the string that the new class received. In a 'regular' print and in error output.

Comment: @Tango_Chaser: You didn't answer my question. Explain how the functionality required differs from `std::cout`.

Comment: @Lightness Races: it does not. it behaves exactly the same.

Comment: @Tango_Chaser: Um, then use `std::cout`.

Comment: @Lightness Races: yes.. well i can't. i need to create my own class to do the same thing.

Comment: @Tango_Chaser: Sorry but that makes very little sense. One concept you need to understand is that `std::cout` and `std::cerr` are instantiations of `std::ostream`; they're not classes. They're instances, pre-defined to use _stdout_ and _stderr_ as their data sinks. You can trivially make your own instantiations that do the same thing, but they will be _identical_, just the same objects, with different names. Utterly pointless. You could reinvent `std::ostream` too if you really want to give yourself more work, but then you're back to "what I found was mostly overriding of the << operator".

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: what you just told me makes sense and helped me understand the problem better. it is EXACTLY what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @Tango_Chaser: If you're making a "mini-OS", there'll be far more value in reimplementing _stdout_ itself if anything. But we don't have any details on the scope of your OS.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, ***don't*** do this unless you know *very* well what you're doing, and are willing to take all of the risks involved.  It's just an example of how one could bind another stream to `stdout`, in effect creating a second `cout`, as a thought experiment.  That said, here we go.

---

If you want to create another stream for `stdout`, you have to take a good look at your compiler's deep, dark innards, and find out how it defines `cout`, `cerr`, and/or `clog`.  This will be in a compiler-dependent location, and most likely not where you expect; for example, on older versions of Visual Studio, you would have to look at a few of the files in the `crt\src` folder:

```
// Visual Studio 2010 implementation of std::cout.
// Irrelevant parts omitted.

// cout.cpp
__PURE_APPDOMAIN_GLOBAL static filebuf fout(_cpp_stdout);
#if defined(_M_CEE_PURE)
__PURE_APPDOMAIN_GLOBAL extern ostream cout(&fout);
#else
__PURE_APPDOMAIN_GLOBAL extern _CRTDATA2 ostream cout(&fout);
#endif

struct _Init_cout
    {
    __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL _Init_cout()
        {
        _Ptr_cout = &cout;
        if (_Ptr_cin != 0)
            _Ptr_cin->tie(_Ptr_cout);
        if (_Ptr_cerr != 0)
            _Ptr_cerr->tie(_Ptr_cout);
        if (_Ptr_clog != 0)
            _Ptr_clog->tie(_Ptr_cout);
        }
    };
__PURE_APPDOMAIN_GLOBAL static _Init_cout init_cout;


// stdio.h
#define _INTERNAL_BUFSIZ 4096
// ...
#define _IOB_ENTRIES 20
// ...
#ifndef _STDSTREAM_DEFINED
#define stdin (&__iob_func()[0])
#define stdout (&__iob_func()[1])
#define stderr (&__iob_func()[2])
#define _STDSTREAM_DEFINED
#endif  /* _STDSTREAM_DEFINED */


// _file.c
char _bufin[_INTERNAL_BUFSIZ];

FILE _iob[_IOB_ENTRIES] = {
    /* _ptr, _cnt, _base,  _flag, _file, _charbuf, _bufsiz */
    /* stdin (_iob[0]) */
    { _bufin, 0, _bufin, _IOREAD | _IOYOURBUF, 0, 0, _INTERNAL_BUFSIZ },
    /* stdout (_iob[1]) */
    { NULL, 0, NULL, _IOWRT, 1, 0, 0 },
    /* stderr (_iob[3]) */
    { NULL, 0, NULL, _IOWRT, 2, 0, 0 },
};
_CRTIMP FILE * __cdecl __iob_func(void)
{
    return _iob;
}


// `__PURE_APPDOMAIN_GLOBAL` is an internal macro that can generally be ignored.
// `_CRTIMP` is an internal macro that can generally be ignored.
// `_CRTDATA2` is an internal macro that can generally be ignored.
// `__CLR_OR_THIS_CALL` is a calling convention macro that expands to either
//   `__clrcall` or `__thiscall`.
```

From this, we can derive our own stream for `stdout`, although it'll be compiler-dependent.

```
// Visual Studio 2010 user-created char16_t cout.
// Note that in VStudio 2010, char16_t is actually a typedef for unsigned short.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>

#define _cpp_stdout (&(__iob_func())[1])
typedef std::basic_filebuf<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>> filebuf_c16;
typedef std::basic_ostream<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>> ostream_c16;

int main() {
    filebuf_c16 f16out(_cpp_stdout);
    ostream_c16 c16out(&f16out);
    // It really should be tied to the other stdin/stdout/stderr streams,
    //   but this is a simple program where it won't be a problem.

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> converter;

    std::string u8tmp = "Hello from char16_t!";
    std::u16string u16str = converter.from_bytes(u8tmp);

    c16out << u16str << std::endl;
}
```

And the results...

```
Hello from char16_t!
```

If you wanted to tie a second standard `ostream` (a.k.a. a `basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char>>`) to `stdout`, you could use something similar.  Note that as `fout` is `static`, you would need to make your own `filebuf`.  Also note that this is just asking for trouble, but that's beside the point; just be careful of data races, or anything of the sort.

---

Note that while you *can* do this, unless you know very well what you're doing, are willing to take responsibility for anything that goes wrong, and are willing to spend enough time delving into your compiler's library and/or code to find out how exactly it implements `stdout` and the default strings, you very well *shouldn't* do it.

Also note that your code will be tightly coupled to the compiler, and there's a very high probability that future versions of the same compiler may break it.  For example, to my knowledge, this code won't compile with Visual Studio 2015 because of changes to the CRT (specifically, I believe it's because of changes to `FILE`, but I didn't look into it).

Answer (score 1):

These objects are `std::ostream`s. You can create your own `std::ostream`. Precisely how that'll work depends entirely on the data sink, which you haven't specified, but an `std::ostringstream` will be enough to get you started on testing the code that uses it.

However, if you literally wish to reinvent `std::cout`, *don't*. Its data sink is the magic file handle *stdout*, which you can't recreate as it's provided by the OS. You could create a `std::ostream` that steals that buffer from `std::cout` but what's the point?

Comment: std::ostringstream helps me use functions on stream, yet it all goes to std::cout at the end.  how do i implement my own cout?

Comment: @Tango_Chaser: _"yet it all goes to std::cout at the end"_ No it doesn't. Perhaps spend more than four minutes looking into it, yeah?

Comment: i will deepen my understanding on that subject, thank you.